# python selenium issue with pop up

Tags: python, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

In our web application, when we click on submit file button , it open up the modal dialog. as attached in the picture below. this is not window based pop up. Looks like browser based modal even not pop up or alert.
I am using selenium and python for automation.
I observed that

1. its no frame --tried switching to frame
2. its a no alert -tried switching to alert
3. its not an new tab or new window- tried to switch to window
4. tried using switch to active element- tried switch to active element
5. Tried by direct providing xpath- here I make sure Xpath is correct in DOM

I tried this code as well -

I have to click on Upload Data File button on the modal. I am not able to click it.

Comment: Please provide at least the entire HTML of that block

Comment: @Prophet, Attached html block of DOM, please let me know if want any more details

Comment: I see. Let me know if what I suggested works

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.upload")
```

should work.
of cause don't forget about kind of wait / delay before this command.
In case the first option doesn't work maybe this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.fileUpload.btn span")
```

**UPD**
You can try uploading the file sending the file path directly to the input element as following:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
elm.send_keys("Your_file_full_path")
```

Comment: I tried your option, those are also not working. Is there any way, we can focus that modal

Comment: If it is just a modal no need to focus on it. is the modal inside the visible area of the screen? maybe you need to scroll to it, move to it with Actions?

Comment: it has no scroll option, but its modal on top of existing browser window. I will try action chain to click but dont think that will focus the element on modal

Comment: Or even try JavaScript click

Comment: Yes tried actions and JavaScript as well not working. Basically when i click on that upload data file button, it will ask to browse the file from windows explorer. Is there any api using which we can upload file for that button

Comment: You can try uploading the file directly. This is the way we usually uploading files with Selenium. However I can't be sure it will work since the first code should be OK, but it doesn't work and I can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Explicit wait :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Uplaod Data File')]")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Make sure that you have a unique entry in DOM. (Press F12 in Chrome and then go to Elements -> CTRL + F then search for `//span[contains(text(), 'Uplaod Data File')]`) and see if there's 1/1 match

**Update 1  :**

try with `ActionChains`

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Uplaod Data File')]")))).click().perform()
```

Comment: I already tried xpath with unique entries  like upload_data_file_button_xpath = "(//div[contains(@class,'modal-body')]//div[contains(@class,'col-md-6')])[1]//span[contains(text(),'Upload Data File')]//following-sibling::input"     or upload_data_file_button_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Upload Data File')]//following-sibling::input"

Comment: What error it threw  ? and did you try with explicit waits too ?

Comment: yes, I tried explicit wait too, by waiting for 1 min and then click...its not able to find element

Comment: No need to wait for 1 min, In case of explicit wait it must have thrown TimeOutException right ? , what exception it threw without explicit wait

Comment: Yes, it is throwing timeout exception after 1min -raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I asked what error did it throw without ExplicitWait  ?

Comment: selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElementsession="e6c42e99ae2220122a9dc761cba6549d", element="54b26279-c668-41e4-a264-13317b99aaef")>
command = 'clickElement'
params = {'id': '54b26279-c668-41e4-a264-13317b99aaef', 'sessionId': 'e6c42e99ae2220122a9dc761cba6549d'}

    def _execute(self, command, params=None):
        """Executes a command against the underlying HTML element.
        Returns:
          The command's JSON response loaded into a dictionary object

Comment: """
        if not params:
            params = {}
        params['id'] = self._id
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)

..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:633: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="e6c42e99ae2220122a9dc761cba6549d")>
driver_command = 'clickElement'
params = {'id': '54b26279-c668-41e4-a264-13317b99aaef'

Comment: Do you have remote web driver instance or chrome driver instance ? See the error at official website - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver

Comment: if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if 'data' in value:
                alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
            elif 'alert' in value:
                alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
raise exception_clas
E       selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element

Comment: ahh okay, I think you would need to launch browser in full screen . try that, if that does not work let me know I have few more ways

Comment: I am already launching browser in maximized mode.

Comment: Alright, Have you tried with ActionsChain  ? something like this `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Uplaod Data File')]")))).click().perform()` - You would imports, that is given with my answer above.

Comment: Yes tried actions as well not working. Basically when i click on that upload data file button, it will ask to browse the file from windows explorer. Is there any api using which we can upload file for that button

Comment: If there's any input with type is equal to file in that page you can use send keys. Just check for input[type='file'] css selector in dev tools. If there's an entry.. you can simply do this driver.find_elemenet(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']").send_keys("D:\somefile")

Comment: how to click first button in case of multiple matches using this - input[type='file'] css selector. We have two buttons on the same modal

Comment: try this xpath : (//input[@type='file'])[1] or [2], but it does not matter in case of file upload. There just have to be a input field with type equals to file.